# Android: does this code make sense?

Tags: android

I want to create a folder "`newFolder`" like this: `a/b/c/newFolder`

Does this code make sense?

```
File path = new File("a/b/c/newFolder");
path.mkdirs();
path.createNewFile();
```

Why do I need `path.createNewFile()`?
Does it create a new File under the "`newFolder`" folder or does it do the same thing as `path.mkdir()`? Thx.

Comment: it creates the file under newFolder instantly.

Comment: but what is the name of the newly created file? If I cannot access the file, it does not make sense to create it right?